# How do young Catholics remember a set of prayers in order to pray the rosary?

Tags: catholicism, religious-education, rosary

How do young Catholics remember a set of prayers in order to pray the rosary? Do they have to memorize everything by rote, or do they get some help with mnemonics? Should they pray in Latin or in the vernacular? Is there a bit of wiggle room if someone is a little amnesic so that they don't have to remember a set of prayers? Would just *reading* the prayers suffice instead of actually memorizing, or is memorizing a form of pious behavior for young people who are taught to become faithful practicing Catholics?

So, I was reading this article [Cunningham, L. S. (1999). Mary in Catholic Doctrine and Practice. Theology Today, 56(3), 307.], and I noticed that the author was raised Catholic as a youngster, as shown.

> By the time I was in elementary school, I knew how to say the
>   rosary-which meant that I had memorized the Hail Mary, the Lord’s
>   Prayer, the Apostle’s Creed, and the Glory be to the Father as well as
>   the titles of the fifteen mysteries upon which we meditated as we
>   prayed.

Comment: Ano., I think none of them.

Answer (score 3):

> How do young Catholics remember a set of prayers in order to pray the rosary? Do they have to memorize everything by rote, or do they get some help with mnemonics?

Rosary is a [combination of many prayers](http://www.rosary-center.org/howtodom.htm) like Apostles' Creed, Our Father, Hail Mary, Glory to the Father.., twenty mysteries divided into four sets,  Hail holy Queen, Litany of Mary etc. All these individual prayers are therefore memorised so that one can say them fluently at the time of their recital. All these prayers are mandatory (to be learnt by heart) before the members are made eligible for Sacraments like First Communion, Confirmation etc.

> Should they pray in Latin or in the vernacular?

All these prayers are said in vernacular languages. In my place the Litany sometimes is still recited in Latin, but that is by a few exceptional groups of people who are of older generation.

> Is there a bit of wiggle room if someone is a little amnesic so that they don't have to remember a set of prayers?

I am not very sure but for such members only the basic prayers like  Apostles creed, Our Father, Hail Mary  are made to remember  so that they become eligible for requisite Sacraments.

> Would just reading the prayers suffice instead of actually memorizing, or is memorizing a form of pious behavior for young people who are taught to become faithful practicing Catholics?

It is necessary and mandatory that all these prayers are memorised and this is usually done at home as well as in the Sunday catechism classes. There are about seven text books that children have to learn and pass during the catechism classes. During these classes they are taught these prayers as well as other tenets of Roman Catholicism/Christianity. But mostly the memorising is done at home. Then they have to answer exams of sort in the catechism classes and pass them. The Sacrament of First Communion is given for those who have learnt and passed first two text books. And those who have completed all the seven would be selected for the Sacrament of Confirmation.

Comment: This answer describes how things are in some Catholic parishes and dioceses, but unfortunately no longer in all. There seems to have been a severe downgrading of religious instructions in the last few decades, to the point where I have read a priest's lament about a teen-ager who not only couldn't recite the Hail Mary but had no idea that it involve more than the two words "Hail Mary".

Answer (score 0):

I am a Catholic, born and raised. I lived in a home where we need to recite the Rosary every day except when we attend Mass on that day. If our work/school schedules are too tight we make it every Saturday.

I would say from experience that no, merely reading it is not enough. I have to recite it regularly to remember it, at least for three months. How schools teach it largely depends. A teacher I know actually makes their students *make* rosaries and have them illustrate guides to the prayers that make up the Holy Rosary, including the Mysteries. There is no limit to the methods to teach the Holy Rosary, as it is in any secular subject.